# Unexpected Token < while running Mean Stack application

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mean-stack

I am following Plurasight video tutorials on creating mean stack application.
http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/building-angularjs-nodejs-apps-mean

[image]
Everything was working fine until morning i found a strange issue of `unexpected token <`

I dint changed any code

scripts.jade

```
script(type="text/javascript",src="/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js")
script(type="text/javascript",src="/vendor/angular/angular.js")
script(type="text/javascript",src="/vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.js")
script(type="text/javascript",src="/vendor/angular-route/angular-route.js")
script(type="text/javascript",src="/app/app.js")
script(type="text/javascript",src="/app/main/mvMainCtrl.js")
script(type="text/javascript",src="/app/account/myNavBarLoginCtrl.js")
```

server.js

```
/**
 * Created by nyaconcepts on 4/10/2014.
 */
var express=require('express'),
    stylus=require('stylus'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    morgan  = require('morgan'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose');

var env=process.env.NODE_ENV=process.env.NODE_ENV||'development';

var app=express();

function compile(str,path){
    return stylus(str).set('filename',path);
}
//Supported by older version
/*app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views',__dirname+'/server/views');
    app.set('view_engine','jade');
});*/

if ('development' == env) {
    app.set('views',__dirname+'/server/views');
    app.set('view engine','jade');
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser());
    app.use(stylus.middleware({
         src:__dirname+'/public',
         compile:compile
        }
    ));
    app.use(express.static(__dirname+'../public'));
  }

if(env=='development'){
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/multivision');
}
else {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://kamlesh:multivision@ds053658.mongolab.com:53658/multivision');
}
var db=mongoose.connection;
db.on('error',console.error.bind(console,'Connection Error..!!'));
db.once('open',function callback(){
    console.log('multivision db opened');
});

/* For displaying partial message
var messageSchema = mongoose.Schema({message: String});
var Message = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);
var mongoMessage;
Message.findOne().exec(function(err, messageDoc) {
    mongoMessage = messageDoc.message;
});*/

app.get('/partials/*', function(req, res) {
    res.render('/../../public/app/' + req.params);
});

app.get('*',function(req,res){
    res.render('index');
        //mongoMessage : mongoMessage
});

var port=process.env.PORT||3030;
app.listen(port);

console.log('Listening on port'+port+'---');
```

Please suggest some solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, I'd bet your routes aren't setup properly and you're loading HTML in all those JS files.

In dev tools, click the right side of one of those syntax errors. [image]

If jquery.js doesn't come up, you need to figure out why. Once you get the correct assets loading, that *should* solve the problem.

Comment: yup i click on those links and html part is loading instead of js files.I had no clue what to do next.

Comment: thanx..my routing was incorrect.i solved it on my own

Comment: @KamleshArya Can you please post your answer then?