# Angular routing in HTML5mode with Node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, angular-ui-router

I know there are other answers to this but they seem to have caveats.

[This one causes a redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19245068/2183008), which can be fatal for my front-end app which uses Mixpanel, and a double-load of Mixpanel will a Maximum Call Stack Size Exceeded error in the browser.

[This one uses `sendFile`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29456345/2183008) which I personally cannot get to work. Trying to diagnose that, I'm just advised to use `express.static()`.

Currently my code looks like this:

home.js - Some routes, the last one intended to be the front-end site.

```
var indexPath = path.resolve( __dirname, '../' + process.env.PUBLIC_FOLDER )

router.get( '/:user/:stream/:slug', function( req, res, next ) {

    if ( req.headers['user-agent'].indexOf( 'facebook' ) != -1 ) {
        // stuff to handle the Facebook crawler
    } else return next()
})

router.get( '/*', function( req, res ) {
    express.static( indexPath )
})
```

server.js - configuring node/express

```
app = express();

app 
    .use( morgan( 'dev' ) )
    .use(bodyParser.urlencoded( { limit: '50mb', extended: true } ) )
    .use( bodyParser.json( { limit: '50mb' } ) )
    .use( '/api', require('./routes/usersRoute.js') )
    .use( '/', require( './routes/home' ) )
    .on( 'error', function( error ){
       console.log( "Error: " + hostNames[i] + "\n" + error.message )
       console.log( error.stack )
    })

http
    .createServer( app ).listen( process.env.PORT )
    .on( 'error', function( error ){
       console.log( "Error: " + hostNames[i] + "\n" + error.message )
       console.log( error.stack )
    })
```

---

Some more info

The reason you can see I'm trying to use `express.static()` is because when I use `res.sendfile()` I get a problem [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23166069/unexpected-token-while-running-mean-stack-application) where the console says `Unexpected token '<'`. Unfortunately the answer doesn't specify an exact fix and neither does the questioner who says they fixed the problem but don't share an answer.

In my trial and error I have added some more to express, like this

```
.use( '/app/app.js', express.static( indexPath + '/app/app.js' ) )
.use( '/app/views', express.static( indexPath + '/app/views' ) )
.use( '/app/controllers', express.static( indexPath + '/app/views' ) )
.use( '/app/directives', express.static( indexPath + '/app/views' ) )
.use( '/app/vendor', express.static( indexPath + '/app/vendor' ) )
.use( '/js', express.static( indexPath + '/js' ) )
.use( '/css', express.static( indexPath + '/css' ) )
.use( '/fonts', express.static( indexPath + '/fonts' ) )
.use( '/images', express.static( indexPath + '/images' ) )
.use( '/api', require('./routes/usersRoute.js') )
.all( '/*', require( './routes/home' ) )
```

And in my `home.js` routes files added this

```
router.get( '/*', function ( req, res ) {
    res.status( 200 ).set( { 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8' } )
    .sendfile( indexPath + '/index.html' )
})
```

And in the browser I can see all my files are loading, but with the `<` error above. I see this `/*/` route is being called hundreds of times when I do a refresh so I think the `.use( '...', ... )` configurations are being ignored.

---

Here is another example requested by Jonas below.

```
var indexPath = path.resolve( __dirname, process.env.PUBLIC_FOLDER )

mongoose.connect( process.env.MONGOLAB_URI )

app = express();

app 
    .use( morgan( 'dev' ) )
    .use(bodyParser.urlencoded( { limit: '50mb', extended: true } ) )
    .use( bodyParser.json( { limit: '50mb' } ) )
    .use( '/api', require('./routes/usersRoute.js') )
    .use( '/', require( './routes/home.js' ) )
    .use( express.static( indexPath ) )
    .on( 'error', function( error ){
       console.log( "Error: " + hostNames[i] + "\n" + error.message )
       console.log( error.stack )
    })
```

I have also done the same without the `.use( '/', require( './routes/home.js' ) )` line to try narrow down any problem, but it's the same result. The page will load if I have the `#` in the URL, but the browser will remove the `#` (so far so good). But if I press refresh, or put in the URL manually, sans-hashbang, it will give an error like `Cannot GET /home/splash`, where `/home/splash` is whatever path I'm going to.

Comment: How do I add a bounty to this? It's been 4 days...

Comment: I'm not an expert with express, but I've never see anyone go wrong when following the samples in the [UI-Router FAQ](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions), which shows using `app.all` rather than `router.get`.

Comment: Did you check the paths passed to `express.static` are valid? What is the value of `indexPath`?

Comment: simply make var app = express();

app.configure(function() {
...
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
...
}

Comment: @PawełSmołka I don't think app.configure is part of express 4.

Comment: Lol ofcourse it is, as a optional but still. http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.configure

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might be using the express middleware in the wrong way. Looking at the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html) tells me for example that the following code

```
.use( '/images', express.static( indexPath + '/images' ) )
```

Serves any file under the folder `indexPath + '/images'` with such URLs:

```
http://localhost:3000/images/kitten.jpg
http://localhost:3000/images/logo.png
http://localhost:3000/images/whatever.jpg
```

*Is that what you would expect it to do?*

My suggestion is to change from

```
.use( '/', require( './routes/home' ) )
```

to

```
.use(express.static( indexPath ))
```

Because according to the documentation, it will serve all static files under the `indexPath` folder from the root path, aka. with no prefix.

I think that is all I can help with the input you gave so far. If that doesn't do the trick, maybe you can share some small code example that I can use to reproduce it on my own.

## UPDATE

Ok. I've tried to create a simple example of it. I made it work in the following way.
My directory structure is like this:

```
|- index.js
|- public/
|---- index.html
|---- test.html
|---- main.js
|---- angular.js
|---- angular-route.js
```

`index.js` is the node server. Pay attention to the **order of the routing**. I also added some `/home/login` example to make it clear how to add other server routes that should not go through angular.

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app
    .use(express.static('public'))
    .get('/home/login', function (req, res) {
        console.log('Login request');
        res.status(200).send('Login from server.');
    })
    .all('/*', function ( req, res ) {
        console.log('All');
        res
            .status( 200 )
            .set( { 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8' } )
            .sendfile('public/index.html' );
    })
    .on( 'error', function( error ){
       console.log( "Error: \n" + error.message );
       console.log( error.stack );
    });

http
    .createServer( app ).listen( 8080 )
    .on( 'error', function( error ){
       console.log( "Error: \n" + error.message );
       console.log( error.stack );
    });

console.log('Serving app on port 8080');
```

`index.html` is pretty simple.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular HTML5 express test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

`main.html` just adds some content. Important is the link to `/test`

```
<div>
    <h1>This is just a {{val}}</h1>
    <button ng-click="clicked()">Click me!</button>
    <span>You clicked {{counter}} times</span>
    <a href="/test">test me!</a>
</div>
```

`test.html` is actually irrelevant

```
<div>
    <h4>What a beautiful day to test HTML5</h4>
</div>
```

`main.js` is doing the core angular html5 work

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider
            .html5Mode({
                enabled: true, // set HTML5 mode
                requireBase: false // I removed this to keep it simple, but you can set your own base url
            });
    })
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/test', {templateUrl: 'test.html', controller: function() {
                console.log('On /test.');
            }})
            .when('/', {templateUrl: 'main.html', controller: 'MyTestCtrl'})
            .otherwise('/');
    })
    .controller('MyTestCtrl', function ($scope) {
        self = $scope;
        self.val = 'TeSt';
        self.counter = 0;
        var self = self;
        self.clicked = function() {
            self.counter++;
        };
    });
```

Comment: When I use `express.static` with HTML5 mode in Angular, I get the error `Cannot GET [path to page]` after refreshing or manually entering a URL. If I add the `#` back to the URL, I can view the page and the # will have been removed.

Comment: @Noah Can you create an example?

Comment: Are you telling me you know for sure that `.use(express.static( indexPath ))` supports HTML5? Because it doesn't seem to. It works until I hit refresh, then it says `Cannot GET /home/splash`. If I put the `#` back in the URL, it loads and removed the `#`, but refreshing again gives the error again.

Comment: I've appended an example above.

Comment: I made an example myself as well. Please check my update to the answer. I hope it clarifies something for you :)

Comment: I think the issue was that I didn't put `.use(express.static('public'))` _first_, I always put it last.

Comment: I found a bug in your code.

<a href="/test/title">test me!</a>

Modifying the router to handle the above link:
.when('/test/title', ........

Cause an infinite loop. You can see it if you look at the console output.

Answer (score 5):

instead of:

```
router.get( '/*', function( req, res ) {
    express.static( indexPath )
})
```

do

```
router.get( '/:anyreq', function( req, res ) {
    express.static( indexPath )
})
```

just keep it at end of routes file.

Comment: I get `Cannot GET /home/login` when using a path and `Cannot GET /` when using a `#` in the path.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there might be a problem with your AJAX requests.
I usually set up my routes like this:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "./public")));
app.use("/", require(path.join(__dirname, "./routes")));`

and make calls on the front end with 
`templateUrl: "/templates/home.html"` in a directive

or `$http.get("/images").success(...).error(...)` using $http.

In the templateUrl case the app will go into the public directory, then the path templates and serve the html file.
In the $http case I'm specifying a route so the app checks the public directory, doesn't see an images path and so moves on to the router.  In the router I have a 
`router.get("/images", function (req, res, next) { res.sendFile(...);` or `res.send({(data)}) })` which sends the file I need back to the front end where it is caught in the success handler.

Comment: I am using `$http` on the front-end and declaring the `templateUrl` like you explain. Are you using `html5Mode`? Can you confirm it works with Express?

Comment: I'm using angular and express with that set up.  In the static router you need to provide the relative path (ie `path.join(__dirname, "public")`)